# what happens if we compare unsigned short int and unsigned char (comparing the bits)? (in C language)

Tags: c, bit, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

For example:

```
    unsigned char mask1 = 0x55; //01010101
    unsigned short int mask2 = 0x8055;//1000000001010101   
    unsigned short int res = 0; //0000000000000000
    res = mask1 | mask2;
```

so what is `res` now in bits?

does it convert `mask1` from 2 bytes to 4? and the "empty spaces" will be zeroes?

I mean, in logical terms it will work like that?

```
res = mask1 | mask2 = 01010101 | 1000000001010101 

  0000000001010101
| 1000000001010101
  ----------------
  1000000001010101
```

Comment: _"and the "empty spaces" will be 0s? "_: what else do you expect?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: in this case the behavior is obvious, but what if `mask1` was defined as `char mask1 = 0x88;` ?

Comment: @chqrlie that's not quite the same question, with `char ...` we'd have sign extension issues, but fair enough.

Comment: "does it convert mask1 from 2 bytes to 4?" That may happen during calculating the result of bitwise OR operation but when that result is assigned to `res` only 2 bytes are kept and the upper part is chopped.

Answer (score 3):

The both operands of the expression

```
mask1|mask2;
```

are converted to the type `int` (or `unsigned int` if the type `int` is unable to represent all values of the operands) due to the *integer promotions* preserving values stored in the operands.

From the C Standard (6.5.12 Bitwise inclusive OR operator)

> 3 The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

and

and (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
> conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
> determine a common real type for the operands and result....
>
> This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
> Otherwise (note: if neither operand is of a real type - added by me),
> the integer promotions are performed on both operands

and (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
> otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
> integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer
> promotions.

So for example the value `0x55` stored in an object of the type `unsigned char` internally will be represented in an object of the type `int` like `0x00000055` provided that the `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`. And the value `0x8055` stored in an object of the type `unsigned short` will be represented internally like `0x00008055`

In this assignment

```
res= mask1|mask2;
```

the result will be converted back to the type `unsigned short`.

Comment: Technically, the integer promotion causes both values to convert to `int` if type `int` is larger than type `short`, otherwise both values are converted to `unsigned int`, but in this particular case, the result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

This answer will assume a mainstream system with 8 bit character types, 16 bit `short` and 32 bit `int` (this is the case for all mainstream 32 and 64 bitters in the real world).

First check out [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). How this works in this particular case:

Each operand in C comes with it's own little line stating how implicit promotions are handled. In case of `|`, we can peek at C17 6.5.12 "the bitwise inclusive OR operator":

> **Constraints**
>
> Each of the operands shall have integer type.
>
> **Semantics**
> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

As we learned from the link at the top of this post, *the integer promotions* are part of *the usual arithmetic conversions*. So in the expression `res = mask1 | mask2;`, both operands are small integer types and therefore promoted to `int` which is signed. Which is a bit unfortunate since we want to avoid bitwise arithmetic using signed operands like the plague, though in this specific case it makes no difference. Instead of 0x8055 and 0x55 we will get 0x00008055 and 0x00000055 - basically just zero padding.

Thus it is 100% equivalent to `res = (int)mask1 | (int)mask2;` and the result of `mask1 | mask2` is of type `int`.

---

Next up this is stored in `res` which is of type `unsigned short`. What happens then is "conversion during assignment", 6.5.16:

> In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the
> assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

The specific rules for what this conversion entails is found in C17 6.3.1.3:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type

This conversion works like modulus, or if you will a binary truncation of the raw value where the most significant bytes are simply discarded.

In this specific case we have an `int` with value `0x00008055` and it is converted to an `unsigned short` with value `0x8055`.

---

A curious note regarding "conversion during assignment" is that is also happens on all of these lines:

```
unsigned char mask1 = 0x55; //01010101
unsigned short int mask2 = 0x8055;//1000000001010101   
unsigned short int res = 0;
```

The numbers here, `0x55` and so forth, are formally called *integer constants*. Integer constants in C have a type picked based on various intricate rules (C17 6.4.4.1) - I won't mention them here but for now we can note that an integer constant can never be of a smaller type than `int`. So during all of the above initializations, we have implicit conversion from `int` to the type of the left operand.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens .. compare `unsigned short int` and `unsigned char` ...?

OP mostly has it.

**Usual promotions**

Operators like `|, ^, &, + , -` and others first *promote* each object that is narrower than `int/unsigned` to `int/unsigned` with no change in *value*.  If `int` encompasses the narrow type range, the object becomes an `int`, otherwise it becomes an `unsigned`.

In OP's case, the `unsigned short int` likely promotes to `int` (or possibly `unsigned` if `unsigned` is 16-bit).  The `unsigned char` certainly becomes an `int`.

**Conversion to common type**

The *lower ranked* object is then convert to the same as the higher ranked one.  This may involve a value change as a negative `int` being converted to an `unsigned` or some integers converted to floating point.

In OP's case, the 2 operands are then `int` (or possibly `unsigned` if `unsigned` is 16-bit).  With OP's values, no value change occurs in this step.

**Operator `|` applied**

`mask1 | mask2` then does almost as OP supposes as 2 `int`s.

```
  0b00000000`00000000`00000000`01010101
| 0b00000000`00000000`10000000`01010101
  -------------------------------------
  0b00000000`00000000`10000000`01010101
```

Or with 16-bit `int/unsigned` as 2 `unsigned`.

```
  0b00000000`01010101
| 0b10000000`01010101
  -------------------
  0b10000000`01010101
```

**Assignment narrows the type**

The `int` (or `unsigned`) result is then converted to `unsigned short` and then assigned.

When the value is representable in the new narrow type, that is the value saved.  Otherwise if the destination type is a *signed* integer, the value is converted in an implementation defined manner.  The most common implementation defined manner simply uses the least significant bits.  Otherwise if the destination type is an *unsigned* integer, the least significant bits are used  (i.e. "mod" (max value + 1)).

In OP's case, the result of `mask1 | mask2` results in a value in the `unsigned short` range and so `0b1000000001010101` is saved.